# Bases for null space and range

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $T: M_n(\mathbb F) \rightarrow \mathbb F$ defined by $T(A)=tr(A)$, where $tr(A)$ means the trace of $A$. Suppose that $T$ is a linear transformation.

I need to find bases for the $N(T)$, the null space of $T$, and for $R(T)$, the range of $T$.

I know that trace is just the sum of the diagonal entries, and the null space is just every $nxn$ matrix with trace zero. But how do I go about finding a basis for $N(T)$?

Thank You

Comment: Let $A = \sum_{i,j=1}^n A_{ij}E_{ij}$. This notation helps. Here $E_{ij}$ is the matrix with one in the $i,j$-th component and zero elsewhere. Further, hint, $E_{22}-E_{11}$ is traceless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trace function is given by the formula $\DeclareMathOperator\tr{tr}\tr(A) = \sum_{i = 1}^n a_{ii}$, where $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix $(a_{ij})$.  Since the off-diagonal entries don't appear, for computations it is a simplification to think of $A$ as being the sum of two matrices, $A = D + B$, where $D$ is the diagonal part and $B$ is the off-diagonal part; $\tr(A) = \tr(D)$ and $\tr(B) = 0$.  This turns the problem into two smaller problems:

1. Find a basis for the kernel of the map $(x_1, \dots, x_n) \mapsto x_1 + \dots + x_n$, where we denote the diagonal entries of $D$ by $x_i = a_{ii}$.
2. Find a basis for the set of matrices $B$ whose diagonal is zero.

The first one is amenable to the usual method for getting a basis for the kernel of a matrix; the second one is amenable to direct inspection.  Does that help?  (I don't think there's any further value in solving the problem here.)

Comment: Thank you. I'm still unsure what you mean by #2 though, why is necessary?

Comment: Think of it this way: for $2 \times 2$ matrices, the trace is a single linear function on a 4-dimensional space, so its kernel has dimension $3$.  One of those dimensions comes from the diagonal matrices: it's a 2-dimensional space and the kernel of the trace in it has dimension 1.  The other two dimensions come from the matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & x \\ y & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, all of which have trace zero and which form a 2-dimensional space.